# Bash: How to capture a real process name and prevent displaying the command process?

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote the next script:

```
process="$1"
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Please specify a process to check"
        exit 1
fi
ps -ef | grep "$process" | grep -v {grep\|$(basename $0)} > /tmp/procs

if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
        stat="OK"
        exitcode="0"
        msg="Process $process is running"
else
        stat="Critical"
        exitcode="2"
        msg="There are currently no running processes of $process"
fi
echo "$stat: $msg"
exit $exitcode
```

The script is supposed to check if a given process is running or not and output a relevant message.

In the script, I'm using the following command to find if the process is running:
`ps -ef | grep $process`

The problem is that while the script is running, the process name also includes the $process word and thus, it finds both the real process and the process of the script (as the $process is mentioned in the command).

Example:

```
[root@pnmnjs2 ~]# sh -x check_proc_nodeJS.sh dakjdhak
+ process=dakjdhak
+ '[' -z dakjdhak ']'
+ ps -ef
++ basename check_proc_nodeJS.sh
+ grep -v '{grep|check_proc_nodeJS.sh}'
+ grep dakjdhak
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ stat=OK
+ exitcode=0
+ msg='Process dakjdhak is running'
+ echo 'OK: Process dakjdhak is running'
OK: Process dakjdhak is running
+ exit 0
[root@pnmnjs2 ~]#
```

Meaning: There is no real process called "dakjdhak" but when the script is running the `ps -ef` command it also catches the process of the running script and then returns that the process exists and running... which is wrong.

How can I "catch" only the relevant process without the process of the running script? 
(the addition of `command | grep -v {grep\|$(basename $0)}` should have done it.. but it doesnt...

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you tried running  `command | grep -v ..` in isolation?

Comment: You can replace the first 5 lines with `process=${1?Please specify a process to check}`.  This has the added benefit of writing the error message to stderr rather than stdout.  Error belong on stderr.  It has the drawback (in some shells) of printing out useless information like the line number in the shell script at which the error occurs.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, Thanks, I've done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little pointer on using your process swtiches

```
ps -ef
```

the -e switch will show **all running processes** this includes when you instantly use the pipe command

```
grep "$process" | grep -v {grep\|$(basename $0)}
```

As a result you will never get an error

example

```
ps -ef|grep "xxx" # if xxx is not running
```

output (your script)

```
OK: Process xxxxxx is running
```

you just executed the process grep which **ran** (it does not matter if grep was successful to the **process command** using -ef argument). The process command see grep ran and as a result no error was caught.

What you can use is

```
ps -A or  ps -C
```

Comment: `grep -v` *excludes* matching lines. It would have worked if the regex were correct (replace `{}` with `""`).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than piping the output of `ps` to `grep`, you can use `pgrep`:

```
# change this
# ps -ef | grep "$process" | grep -v {grep\|$(basename $0)} > /tmp/procs

# if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
# to this
if pgrep "$process" > /tmp/procs; then
```

If you want to know the return value of a command, there's no need to use `$?` with `[` - just test the command directly.

Comment: I'm not sure about this syntax... can you please show an example over my script?

Comment: @Itai I have updated my code, does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ps -C "$process"` to find a process using its executable name ([`comm`, not `args`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)).